# Footer com uma só linha

Tags: html, css

Estou utilizando bootstrap para fazer um footer, porem atualmente ele esta jogando cada elemento em uma linha assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu queria que ele ficasse em uma unica linha assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container ">
        <img src="imgs/logobranco.png">
        <p>© 2018 Do Up English.</p><p> Todos os direitos reservados a Do Up English</p>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Css atual:

```
    .footer{
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    padding: 1rem;

}
.footer .container img{
    height:1.7rem;
}
.footer .container p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como vc está usando o Bootstrap coloque os elementos do Footer dentro do Grid do framework ex. `<div class="col-xs-6">`. Depois disso use `float:right` apenas onde está usando o Fontawesom desse forma

```
.footer .container a{
    float: right;
}
```

Veja abaixo o resultado:

```css
.footer{
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.footer .container img{
    height:1.7rem;
}
.footer .container p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
.footer .container a{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <img src="http://placeskull.com/150/50">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <p>© 2018 Do Up English.</p><p> Todos os direitos reservados a Do Up English</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Esquece, eu entendi errado xD, notei agora, esta mesmo usando bootstrap :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o que vale é a intenção =D

Answer (score 6):

Basta usar `float:` e separar cada um em um elemento, por exemplo:

> **Nota:** o pseudo elemento `:after` em `.footer .container:after` é apenas uma técnica para quebrar os floats se necessário, acaso a coluna `col-l` ou `col-r` seja maior que a coluna `col-c`

```css
.footer{
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    padding: 1rem;

}
.footer .container img{
    height:1.7rem;
}
.footer .container p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}

.footer .container .col-l {
     float: left; /*flutua para a esquerda*/
}
.footer .container .col-r {
     float: right; /*flutua para a direita*/
}
.footer .container:after {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<!-- somente para funcionar os icone fontawesome, pode ignorar esta parte -->
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>


<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-l">
             <img src="imgs/logobranco.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-r">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-c">
           <p>© 2018 Do Up English.</p>
           <p>Todos os direitos reservados a Do Up English</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema aí é o `<p>` que ocupa toda a largura do `footer`. Converta-o em `display: inline-block` e coloque o `text-align: center` no `footer`.

Envolva os ícones das redes sociais em um `span` e coloque `float: right`. E coloque `float: left` na imagem.

Quanto ao uso do `<p>` no texto, em vez de usar 2 `<p>`, use apenas 1 e quebre a linha dos textos com `<br />`.

**Veja:**

```css
.footer{
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer .container img{
    height:1.7rem;
    float: left;
}
.footer .container p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer .container span{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

<footer class="footer">
   <div class="container ">
      <img src="imgs/logobranco.png">
      <p>
         © 2018 Do Up English.
         <br />
         Todos os direitos reservados a Do Up English
      </p>
      <span>
         <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
      </span>
   </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode colocar cada grupo de coisas do footer (imagem, texto e ícones) em divs separadas e usar `display: inline-block` nas divs.
Fácil, sem precisar de `float` e mais organizado:

```css
.footer{
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    padding: 1rem;

}
.footer .container img{
    height:1.7rem;
}
.footer .container p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer class="footer">
   <div class="container">
      <div>
         <img src="imgs/logobranco.png">
      </div>
      <div>
         <p>© 2018 Do Up English.</p>
         <p> Todos os direitos reservados a Do Up English</p>
      </div>
      <div>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x footericone"></i></a>
      </div>
   </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Aonde exatamente `display: inline-block` é mais organizado que `float`, que fator de comparativo usou para determinar isto exatamente? Poderia explicar a sua colocação?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento isso mereceria um post só sobre o assunto, mas o objetivo do float é dizer como um elemento "flutua" em relação aos outros elementos ao seu redor (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/float) , e o display com inline-block diz que os elementos serão alinhados em linha como blocos, o que me parece muito mais adequado para o layout dessa pergunta, deixando mais "claro" o que está acontecendo no layout. 
Tem um post bem legal do SO inglês sobre esse assunto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/advantages-of-using-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft-in-css

Comment: Usando display, também não é necessário usar float nos elementos da esquerda e direita, deixando o próprio navegador organizar a posição das divs dentro do seu container, por isso acho mais organizado, mas não é uma questão absoluta, só preferência mesmo, o float também resolve esse problema

Comment: O "proprio navegador", isso não faz sentido, a renderização funciona baseada no box-model, você esta colocando afirmações que mais me parecem baseadas em opinião pessoal do que você se sente mais confortável em trabalhar e não sobre o funcionamento do motor e comportamento do box-model, sinceramente isto de ser melhor ou não é mais questão de dominio e entendimento.

Comment: quando disse "o próprio navegador" estava me referindo ao motor.
Veja, não tenho nada contra o `float`, aliás uso bastante mas, sematicamente, ele foi adicionado para que um elemento flutue e os demais elementos no mesmo container se alinhem ao redor dele, por isso acho que, semanticamente falando, se o objetivo é alinhar em linha vários elementos, o `display` é mais adequado, só isso, o que não quer dizer que seja melhor ou não, apenas o `inline-block` me parece deixar "mais claro" o objetivo do layout.

Comment: Encontrei um outro post bem interessante que aborda várias diferenças de comportamento entre `display` e `float`, coisas que eu mesmo não havia notado, vale a leitura: https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/css-float-vs-inline-block-qual-usar-em-meus-layouts/

Comment: Desculpe, pra mim isso é opinião pessoa sua da maneira de que se sente confortável para trabalhar e dominio melhor sobre o inline-block, mas isso não indica em nada que um é melhor que outro, tendo domínio e conhecimento/pratica e principalmente entendendo o comportamento do **box-model** você vai ter controle e entendimento do que ocorre, sendo `float` ou sendo `inline-block`.

Comment: Ricardo, esse link que você citou, em nenhum momento o autor cita fontes como W3, não fala de box-model e ainda por cima parece que é só uma série de testes pessoais, eu não recomendaria este artigo pra ninguém. Desculpe, mas preciso ser sincero.

Comment: Tranquilo pode ser sincero rs.. a ideia foi só compartilhar um link que mostra testes práticos do comportamento do float e do display, não é um link de estudo nem nada do gênero, apenas pra complementar o que estávamos falando